# A question on bivariate recurrence

Tags: recurrences

Is there a way to get a closed form of this recurrence (albeit approximate):

$$A(n ,k ) = {1 \over {d^k}}A(n-1, k-1) + (1 - {1 \over {d^k}})A(n-1,k)$$

Where, $n,k \ge 0$ and $d \ge 2$ are integers. Further more, $A(n, k) = 0$ for $k \ge n$. Using generating functions I get the following solutions:

$$A(n,k)=1 - \sum_{i=1}^k \left(1-d^{-i}\right)^{n-1}\left(\prod_{j=1,j \neq i}^k\left( 1- d^{j - i}\right) \right)^{-1}$$

If I unroll the recurrence directly, I get:
$$A(n, k) = ({d^{k(k+1)/2}})^{-1}\sum_{i_1 = k}^{n-k-1}...\sum_{i_k = 1}^{i_{k-1}-1}(1 - {1 \over {d^k}})^{n-k-i_1}...(1 - {1 \over d})^{i_{k-1}-i_k - 1}$$

What I ideally want is a bound of the form: $A(n,k) \le n^{f(k,d)}$, where, $f(k,d)$ is a closed function of $k,d$.

Comment: Can you tell us something about the numbers A(n,0) ?

Comment: $A(n,0) = 1$ for $n > 0$. Sorry, forgot to mention that.

Comment: If so, you have $0\leq A(n,k)\leq 1$ for all $n$ and $k$.

Comment: Yes, that is not what I am looking though.

Comment: I'm sorry but $1=n^0$ and $0$ is a closed function of $k,d$. This is exactly what you asked for.

Comment: I need to know how this function grows with n, the exponent can be negative. Although $n^0$ works, it is a trivial bound, I assumed it was clear from my description that it was clear, I guess not.